# Frozen processes: JOINing using OR vs AND

Tags: mysql, join

On my site I have a query building tool where users can drag and drop blocks to form basic (and sanitized!) SQL queries.  Last week someone created this seemingly benign query that hung up all other queries to their schema (making their entire system unusable):

```
SELECT clients.id_client
FROM clients
INNER JOIN cases ON clients.id_client=cases.id_client
INNER JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
WHERE cases.date>=1444176000 OR locations.type IN (7)
```

I use a GCE LAMP stack Standard Instance.  It typically runs at 10% CPU utilization.  This spiked it at 100% and kept it there for a couple hours before my client called me to say no one was able to access the system.

The clients table has 25,000 entries.  Cases has 55,000.  Locations has 20,000.

So... okay, I get it... Joining all three of those tables takes some time.  BUT in running some tests on what went wrong I tried replacing the OR with AND to produce:

```
SELECT clients.id_client
FROM clients
INNER JOIN cases ON clients.id_client=cases.id_client
INNER JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
WHERE cases.date>=1444176000 AND locations.type IN (7)
```

And that came back in a fraction of a second.

Why does using AND take a tenth of a second but using OR takes over two hours?  With both queries, doesn't mySQL still need to JOIN all three tables first in order to produce the final result?

It also might be interesting to note that removing the actual usage of the locations table *doesn't* crash:

```
SELECT clients.id_client
FROM clients
INNER JOIN cases ON clients.id_client=cases.id_client
INNER JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
WHERE cases.date>=1444176000
```

While removing the actual usage of the cases table ALMOST does:

```
SELECT clients.id_client
FROM clients
INNER JOIN cases ON clients.id_client=cases.id_client
INNER JOIN locations ON clients.id_client=locations.id_client
WHERE locations.type IN (7)
```

With that one, the server maxes to 100%, all other connections to the same schema are frozen, but a result is returned in about 2.5 minutes (even though phpMyAdmin claims that it only took a fraction of a second) and everything goes back to normal.

Again, the cases table is much larger and has a lot more columns than the locations table.  So I would have guessed keeping the cases table in the WHERE would have been more problematic than keeping the locations table.

Comment: Do you have an index on location.type? If not, create an index on location.type and re-run the last query with only location.type in (7). The amount of data may also cause delay. Try doing `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` using `and` and `or` to see the number of records returned. How many records appeared?

Comment: I previously tried setting an index on the type column in the locations table and that didn't help.  Using SELECT COUNT(*) with AND produced a result of 1.  Replacing that with OR stalled the server in the same was as described above.

Comment: Good info. Could you run `select count(*) ...` and leave out the WHERE clause? How long does that take to run? What is the count you receive? I suspect it would be around 50-60K records.

Comment: Sorry @zedfloxus, didn't want to try that in the middle of the day when people were using my system.  Looks like doing as you suggested spiked the system again.  So no response.  But yes, I would expect around 60k records too.  Only a handful of clients have more than one location, so I'd expect to see just a few more results than the number of cases.

Comment: So the next step would be to do `EXPLAIN select ...` without the `where` clause. Can you please edit the post and add `EXPLAIN select...`'s output? Doing so will not load your database server.